# Assign an image dynamically in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I assign an image dynamically in flutter ? For example:

```dart
    final topContent = Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0),
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.5,
            decoration: new BoxDecoration(
              image: new DecorationImage(
                image: new AssetImage(lesson.imagePath),
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            )),
        Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.5,
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(40.0),
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Color.fromRGBO(58, 66, 86, .9)),
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            controller: _scrollController,
            child: Center(
              child: topContentText,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Positioned(
          left: 8.0,
          top: 60.0,
          child: InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
            child: Icon(Icons.arrow_back, color: Colors.white),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
```

Now the image at the start `lesson.imagePath` is what I want to change dynamically. I tried to use `setState()` but it gives me an error:

> The expression here is a type of void and cannot be used

```dart
image: setState ((){
 if (someCondition) {
 return new AssetImage(lesson.imagePath); 
 }
}),
```

Comment: how can i achieve this in StatelessWidget?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your setState call is wrong! The most simple way is make your image as state of your widget and update this image inside a `setState` call. `setState` method does not returns nothing it just rebuilds your widget.

In your _WidgetState class you declare as member:

```
AssetImage _imageToShow;
```

You can provider a initial image inside `initState` method.

```
@override
initState(){
   _imageToShow = AssetImage('youAssetImage');
}
```

Your Container widget should be declared as:

```
Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0),
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.5,
            decoration: new BoxDecoration(
              image: new DecorationImage(
                image: _imageToShow,
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            )),
 ),
```

And to update your image with setState call you just need:

```
void updateImage() {
   setState ((){ 
      if (someCondition) {
        _imageToShow = new AssetImage(lesson.imagePath); 
      }
    });
}
```

But remember that something has to call `updateImage` method.

Answer (score 0):

The above solution can work also you can set an array of names and you can set the same image name in the assets folder and you can dynamically select the image where you want to use.
suppose in your case you have a list of lessons.

```
var lesson = ['a','b','c'];
```

In assets, folder give the same name to the images. (Don't forget to update the `pubspec.yaml` file)

Then in the `AssetImage` you can give the path which can be chosen dynamically.

```
image:AssetImage('assets/${lesson[index]}.jpg')
```

Remember to give the same name to the image like here `a,b and c` to the image.

Also the same extension to be given like here `.jpg`

```
image:AssetImage('assets/${lesson[index]}.jpg')
```